# LookupEdit: how to verify whether user changed value or not inside EditValueChanging event?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to raise warning dialog when user manually changes value from a couple of drop-down list. In case of negative answer previous value must be restored, so i decided to use *EditValueChanging event. But there is also one main drop-down list that also changes the value of all desired controls (some sort of default values setup) which causes multiple dialog messages to appear for each control which is not desirable. How can i verify that valuee were changed by user, not by code, to raise dialog window?

Comment: Are you using WinForms/WPF/Silverlight/ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean value when you update the values from your "default values" setup and unset it when that routine completes, then predicate the EditValueChanging based on whether the boolean is set.